# Dropdown issue, propably rookie mistake

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am fairly new in coding and I am trying to create a dropdown menu but can't seem to make it work. I have seen similar questions here and read through almost all of them but me beeing new to this I am not able to apply any of those answers to my code, so that's why I believe a more personalised answer would be a good way for me to understand what's up. It's either something I don't understand about dropdowns or a silly typo that I can't find so any help would be appreciated. Especially any help that could make me understand my error.

I would like to avoid using Bootstrap in order to get a better understanding about how things work.

```css
.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

.navcontainer {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navcontainer__active {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown-content:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown-content_dropdown-link {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown:hover .navcontainer__dropdown__dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navcontainer__navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navcontainer__item {
  float: left;
}

.navcontainer__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navcontainer__link:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 95%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
  background-image: url("/src/images/news.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf8;base64,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 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<title>News Website</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/css/styles.css">
<head>
 
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<header class="header"> 
 <img src="src/images/logo.png" class="header__logo" alt="Logo">
</header>

<div class="navcontainer">
 <ul class="navcontainer__navbar">
  <li class="navcontainer__item navcontainer__active"><a class="navcontainer__link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="navcontainer__item">
   <a class="navcontainer__link navcontainer__dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">Categories</a>
    <div class="navcontainer__dropdown-content">
   <a class="navcontainer__dropdown-link" href="#">Politics</a>
   <a class="navcontainer__dropdown-link" href="#">Sports</a>
   <a class="navcontainer__dropdown-link" href="#">Finance</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="navcontainer__item"><a class="navcontainer__link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="navcontainer__item"><a class="navcontainer__link" href="#about">About</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
 Hello World!
 
</div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

Comment: Your selector `.navcontainer__dropdown:hover .navcontainer__dropdown__dropdown-content` will never match anything - because `.navcontainer__dropdown__dropdown-content` is not a _descendant_ of `.navcontainer__dropdown`, but the “space” between those two selectors is the _descendant_ combinator. To select the immediately following sibling of the hovered element, you would need to use the adjacent sibling combinator instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors

Comment: I agree wth @J.vee. To be more specific you can see the explanation from this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp)

Comment: Will read that very carefully, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some css please check it.

Your dropdown is child of `li` tag so that below css not work for this

```
.navcontainer__dropdown:hover .navcontainer__dropdown__dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Instead of use this:

```
.navcontainer__item:hover .navcontainer__dropdown-content {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  display: block;
}
```

Also you need to remove overflow for the `ul`, other wise you can not show the dropdown.

One more point when you used `absolute` position please make sure that it's parent have relative position.

```css
.flex-container {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.header__logo {
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
}

.navcontainer {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.navcontainer__active {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 160px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0; /*New css added */
  top: 100%; /*New css added */
}

/*New css added */
.navcontainer__item:hover .navcontainer__dropdown-content {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  display: block;
}

/*New css added */
.navcontainer__dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
/*New css added */
.navcontainer__dropdown-content a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown-content_dropdown-link {
  color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.navcontainer__dropdown:hover .navcontainer__dropdown__dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navcontainer__navbar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  max-width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}
.navcontainer__navbar:after{
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.navcontainer__item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.navcontainer__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 9px 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navcontainer__link:hover {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 95%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

body {
  background-image: url("/src/images/news.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<title>News Website</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/css/styles.css">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header">
            <img src="src/images/logo.png" class="header__logo" alt="Logo">
        </header>
        <div class="navcontainer">
            <ul class="navcontainer__navbar">
                <li class="navcontainer__item navcontainer__active"><a class="navcontainer__link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="navcontainer__item">
                    <a class="navcontainer__link navcontainer__dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)">Categories</a>
                    <div class="navcontainer__dropdown-content">
                        <a class="navcontainer__dropdown-link" href="#">Politics</a>
                        <a class="navcontainer__dropdown-link" href="#">Sports</a>
                        <a class="navcontainer__dropdown-link" href="#">Finance</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="navcontainer__item"><a class="navcontainer__link" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="navcontainer__item"><a class="navcontainer__link" href="#about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-container">
            Hello World!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now it is a nice anwer :)

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot, I still don't understand why you did many of the other changes you did though, like not hide the overflow on navbar.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSS, it looks like a typing error on your part.

```
.navcontainer__dropdown:hover .navcontainer__dropdown__dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Looks like you have an extra **dropdown** word in there. try

```
.navcontainer__dropdown:hover .navcontainer__dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: That was a typo indeed,Thank you!